# Given all parameters, how can the offset of a torus in front of a cylinder so that their edges line up be calculated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, dynamically-generated

I have two mesh types that are automatically generated - a torus and a cylinder.
The torus provides random curves, while the cylinder provides straight pathways.
They use roughly the same variables, and are compatible with eachother so that changes made to one type reflect the other.

However, I've run into a problem where I can't get a torus to connect to the end
of a cylinder. It works just fine in the opposite direction - connecting cylinder to the end of a torus.

I've been following this tutorial, however I added the additional cylinder segments in:

http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/swirly-pipe/

This is my problem thus far:

[image]

Here is the code that I have for this - each function for the cylinders are marked with the word Cylinder on them:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Pipe : MonoBehaviour {

    public float pipeRadius;
    public float cylinderRingDistance;

    public int pipeSegmentCount;

    public Vector3 cVector;

    public float ringDistance;

    public float minCurveRadius, maxCurveRadius;
    public int minCurveSegmentCount, maxCurveSegmentCount;

    private float curveRadius;
    private int curveSegmentCount;

    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    private int[] triangles;

    private float curveAngle;

    public bool Torus = true;

    // Create the dynamic mesh
    private void Awake () {
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.name = "Pipe";

        curveRadius = Random.Range(minCurveRadius, maxCurveRadius);
        curveSegmentCount =
        Random.Range(minCurveSegmentCount, maxCurveSegmentCount + 1);



}

    // Use random input to select either torus or cylinder
    public void BuildTorusOrCylinder(bool torus = true)
    {
        if (torus)
        {
            BuildTorus();
        } else {
            BuildCylinder();
        }

        Torus = torus;
    }

    // Build a Torus-based pipe
    private void BuildTorus()
    {
        SetVertices();
        SetTriangles();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

    // Build a Cylinder-based pipe
    private void BuildCylinder()
    {
        SetVerticesCylinder();
        SetTrianglesCylinder();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

    // Generate the related vertices for a torus
    private void SetVertices () {
        vertices = new Vector3[pipeSegmentCount * curveSegmentCount * 4];

        float uStep = ringDistance / curveRadius;
        curveAngle = uStep * curveSegmentCount * (360f / (2f * Mathf.PI));
        CreateFirstQuadRing(uStep);
        int iDelta = pipeSegmentCount * 4;
        for (int u = 2, i = iDelta; u <= curveSegmentCount; u++, i += iDelta) {
            CreateQuadRing(u * uStep, i);
        }
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
    }

    // Create the first ring of a torus mesh
    private void CreateFirstQuadRing (float u) {
        float vStep = (2f * Mathf.PI) / pipeSegmentCount;

        Vector3 vertexA = GetPointOnTorus(0f, 0f);
        Vector3 vertexB = GetPointOnTorus(u, 0f);
        for (int v = 1, i = 0; v <= pipeSegmentCount; v++, i += 4) {
            vertices[i] = vertexA;
            vertices[i + 1] = vertexA = GetPointOnTorus(0f, v * vStep);
            vertices[i + 2] = vertexB;
            vertices[i + 3] = vertexB = GetPointOnTorus(u, v * vStep);
        }
    }

    // Create the rings of a torus mesh 
    private void CreateQuadRing (float u, int i) {
        float vStep = (2f * Mathf.PI) / pipeSegmentCount;
        int ringOffset = pipeSegmentCount * 4;

        Vector3 vertex = GetPointOnTorus(u, 0f);
        for (int v = 1; v <= pipeSegmentCount; v++, i += 4) {
            vertices[i] = vertices[i - ringOffset + 2];
            vertices[i + 1] = vertices[i - ringOffset + 3];
            vertices[i + 2] = vertex;
            vertices[i + 3] = vertex = GetPointOnTorus(u, v * vStep);
        }
    }

    // Create the triangles for a torus mesh //
    private void SetTriangles () {
        triangles = new int[pipeSegmentCount * curveSegmentCount * 6];
        for (int t = 0, i = 0; t < triangles.Length; t += 6, i += 4) {
            triangles[t] = i;
            triangles[t + 1] = triangles[t + 4] = i + 1;
            triangles[t + 2] = triangles[t + 3] = i + 2;
            triangles[t + 5] = i + 3;
        }
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }

    // Generate the torus structure 
    private Vector3 GetPointOnTorus (float u, float v) {
        Vector3 p;
        float r = (curveRadius + pipeRadius * Mathf.Cos(v));
        p.x = r * Mathf.Sin(u);
        p.y = r * Mathf.Cos(u);
        p.z = pipeRadius * Mathf.Sin(v);
        return p;
    }

    // Generate the cylinder structure
    private Vector3 GetPointOnCylinder(float u, float v)
    {
        Vector3 p;
        p.x = u * cylinderRingDistance;
       p.y = pipeRadius * Mathf.Cos(v);
        p.z = pipeRadius * Mathf.Sin(v);
        return p;
    }

    // Create the vertices for a cylinder mesh
    private void SetVerticesCylinder()
    {
        int vertLimit = (pipeSegmentCount * 2) * 4;
        vertices = new Vector3[vertLimit];
        float uStep = (2f * Mathf.PI) / pipeSegmentCount;

        float vStep = (2f * Mathf.PI) / pipeSegmentCount;
        curveRadius = 0f;
        Vector3 vertexA = GetPointOnCylinder(0f, 0f);
        Vector3 vertexB = GetPointOnCylinder(uStep, 0f);
        for (int v = 1, i = 0; v <= pipeSegmentCount; v++, i += 4)
        {
            vertices[i] = vertexA;
            vertices[i + 1] = vertexA = GetPointOnCylinder(0f, v * vStep);
            vertices[i + 2] = vertexB;
            vertices[i + 3] = vertexB = GetPointOnCylinder(uStep, v * vStep);


        }

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
    }

    // Set the mesh triangles for texturing - Cylinder version //
    private void SetTrianglesCylinder()
    {
        triangles = new int[pipeSegmentCount * 6];
        for (int t = 0, i = 0; t < triangles.Length; t += 6, i += 4)
        {
            triangles[t] = i;
            triangles[t + 1] = triangles[t + 4] = i + 1;
            triangles[t + 2] = triangles[t + 3] = i + 2;
            triangles[t + 5] = i + 3;
        }
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }

    // Take the previous pipe, determine which type it is and properly align
    public void AlignWith(Pipe pipe)
    {
        float relativeRotation =
        Random.Range(0, curveSegmentCount) * 360f / pipeSegmentCount;

        transform.SetParent(pipe.transform, false);
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -pipe.curveAngle);

        if (pipe.Torus)
        {
            transform.Translate(0f, pipe.curveRadius, 0f);
            transform.Rotate(relativeRotation, 0f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(0f, -curveRadius, 0f);
        } else {
            transform.Translate(0f, pipe.curveRadius, 0f);
            transform.Rotate(relativeRotation, 0f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(0f, -curveRadius, 0f);
        }

        transform.SetParent(pipe.transform.parent);
    }
}
```